# Cant' Display Custom Post Type Title Base on Tax Terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, loop

Trying to list all Custom Post Type titles based on filtered Custom Taxonomy Terms I am getting the list of all post titles instead of getting the list of Queried post.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( 
   array( 
        'post_type' => 'photos', 
        'technique' => 'zevar', 
        'post_child' => 0, 
        'posts_per_page' => 10 
   ) 
); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

As you can see I have a Custom Post Type called "photos" and Custom Taxonomy registered as "technique". Under Taxonomy "technique" I have some terms which one of them is "zevar".
Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `{tax} => {term}` pattern is deprecated as of 3.1 you should be using [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), but your code should still work for some undetermined length of time.
2. `post_child` is not a parameter that [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) accepts. I don't know what you expect that to do but at best it does nothing. This may be breaking you query, but I doubt it. I would expect it to be simply ignored.

What you should be using is this, pretty much straight from the Codex:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'photos',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'technique',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'zevar'
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 10 
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

That code, plus a readable `while` loop...

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
}
```

... does work. I tested it. Of course, you have to have the taxonomy setup correctly and you have to have posts in the post type with the right term.

Comment: s_ha_dum, Thanks for ur great help.it is working but the only thing which I cant' understand is this part field' => 'slug',
'terms' => 'zevar'! why did you chose the 'slug'? does this mean i have to specify my custom taxonomy's slug? once again thanks for your help.

Comment: No. You specify whether you are identifying the term by either the slug or the ID. See the Codex page for `WP_Query`